# No reverse match with comments

Tags: django, comments

I want to display my comment form in my page. However, every time i enter the page i get no reverse match error. Maybe there is something to do with form action, but honestly I have no idea what to do. Please help!

**views.py**

```
def single_blog(request, pk):
    news = News.objects.filter(pk=pk)
    comment_form = CommentForm()
    context = {
        'title': 'Новость',
        'news': news,
        'comment_form': comment_form
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/single-blog.html', context)

def save_comment(request, pk, new_pk):
    form = CommentForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.instance.new_id = new_pk
        comment = form.save()
        return redirect('single-blog', pk)
```

**models.py**

```
class Comments(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(News, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Автор')
    text = models.TextField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Текст')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Дата публикации')
```

**urls.py**

```
path('single-blog/<int:pk>', single_blog, name='single-blog'),
path('save_comment/<int:pk>', save_comment, name='save_comment')
```

**html**

##### Leave a Reply

```
                <form class="form-contact comment_form" action="{% url 'save_comment' new_pk %}" id="commentForm">
                    {% csrf_token %}

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                {{ comment_form.author }}
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                {{ comment_form.text }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what it is "new_pk".

first, you should check "new_pk" value.

if "new_pk" value are not integer value, django will triyng to find another URL pattern